# Error in selecting multiple, non-sequential columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, rows

I am running DESeq2 analysis and I have to select a few columns from the count matrix and the corresponding rows from the information matrix. In the matrix Cina_DE, I have to select columns 1-3 and 7-9, and in Cina_DE_info I have to select rows 1-3 and 7-9

```
Cina_DE <- Cina_DE[,c(1:3,7:9)]
Cina_DE_info <- Cina_DE_info [c(1:3,7:9),]
```

I am getting this error

> Error in `[.data.frame`(Cina_DE, , c(1:3, 7:9)) : undefined columns selected

The same code is working if I am selecting columns sequentially starting from 1. If I don't start from 1, I am getting this error.

Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Comment: What result do you get from `dim(Cina_DE)`?

Comment: (Odd, you type in `MT_count[,c(1:3,7:9)]` and get an error about a completely different variable named `Cina_DE`. I can't say I've ever see that happen. Did you mis-type your sample code in the question?)

Comment: @r2evans I am sorry. MT_count is same as Cina_DE. I wanted to make it a universal example so I changed the name of the matrix. I am editing it to Cina_DE now.

Comment: @AllanCameron dimensions of Cina_DE are 117382 *  9

Comment: What about `dim(Cina_DE_info)`? Is it transposed in a sense, where columns in `Cina_DE` correspond to rows in `Cina_DE_info`?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, Cina_DE_info is so transposed that columns of Cina_DE correspond to rows in Cina_DE_info. Its dimensions are 9 * 3

Comment: Can you please provide the output from `dput(head(Cina_DE))`?

Comment: @r2evans the output from dput(head(Cina_DE)) is  
structure(list(S1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), S3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SA1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SA2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SA3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SZ1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), SZ2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SZ3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("S1_SOAP.k25.C299279", 
"S1_SOAP.k25.C302421", "S1_SOAP.k25.C304073", "S1_SOAP.k25.C305432", 
"S1_SOAP.k25.C306484", "S1_SOAP.k25.C308448"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: When I assign that 6-row structure to `Cina_DE` locally, I can do the subset without error. There must be something else you're not showing, because this is not reproducible. (In the future, please put data and code in the question itself: comments are often too short, are easily missed by readers, and (when there are a lot of comments) can be hidden by the interface.

Comment: The problem isn't that I can't subset. If I am subsetting starting from column 1, I can do this. For example, `Cina_DE[,c(1:6)]` works absolutely fine. But if I select columns as  `Cina_DE[,c(2:5)]` or `Cina_DE[,c(1:3,7:9)]` that shows error. In the latter case, upon inspecting the data, 1:3 columns are selected but not 7:9.